# In handler of gridready oif aggrid got getDisplayedRowCount()=1 also in the case when actual number of rows > 1

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have handler for AGGrid (with server row model) gridReady event handling  , where I expected to get count of rows at the end of the handler.

```
const onGridReadyHandler = useCallback(
        async (event: GridReadyEvent) => {
            if (serverSide) {
                if (serverSide.onGridReady) {
                    await serverSide.onGridReady(event); 
                }
                ...
            }
            setGridReady(true);
            console.log('Displayed rows : ' + event.api.getDisplayedRowCount());  ---> displayed 1 also in the case when rowscount >1 
        },
        .....
    );
```

But in call of console.log I get getDisplayedRowCount() =1 .
When selecting some row , value returned by getDisplayedRowCount() > 1 - as expected .
The question - what can cause of such behavior ? Is there missing something ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have displayed row count, shift your attention to this grid event: [onModelUpdated](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous-modelUpdated)

> Displayed rows have changed. Triggered after sort, filter or tree expand / collapse events.

To get displayed row count in SSRM, you can use this event like that

```
const onModelUpdated = useCallback((params) => {
  console.log('row count: ', params.api.getDisplayedRowCount());
}, []);
```

[image: Reference Picture]

Here's a plunker as a reference: https://plnkr.co/edit/pbpDu95BLRlGQWUE?preview

Comment: If it is worked for you, please mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `onGridReady` event is giving you an incorrect row count because you're using the server-side row model. With this model, rows are only loaded in blocks, so when the `onGridReady` event is triggered, only the first block of rows is loaded. This is why the `getDisplayedRowCount()` method only returns 1.

To get the total count of all rows, including the ones that haven't been loaded yet, you can use the `getTotalRowCount()` method from the `GridApi` object. This will give you the actual number of rows in your grid.

```
const onGridReadyHandler = useCallback(
    async (event: GridReadyEvent) => {
        if (serverSide) {
            if (serverSide.onGridReady) {
                await serverSide.onGridReady(event); 
            }

        }
        setGridReady(true);
        console.log('Total rows: ' + event.api.getTotalRowCount());  // returns the actual row count 
    },

);
```

server-side row model here: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/server-side-model/

Comment: Hello @Afzal K. - thanks for quick reply , but here  https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/server-side-model/ was not found getTotalRowCount() , only  getDisplayedRowCount() .